# Linked List insertion(classes used)

Tags: c++

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
   ListItem<T> *node=new ListItem<T>(item);
   ListItem<T> *temp;

   temp=head;
   head=node;
   head->next=temp;
   temp->prev=head;
}
```

Can somebody please point out what is wrong with this piece of code?I m making a linked list with classes.I would really appreciate it

Comment: For us to tell you what is wrong with the code, you could help us by telling what is not working.

Comment: You mean besides not checking for null-pointers?

Comment: It could be that head is point to 0x0000 and when you do that it should crash at "head->next = temp;"

Comment: the thing is i have an assignment to make the linked list and our professor has given us a test file to test this code but the test file is giving me a failing grade for this part.I can't understand whats the problem because t looks perfectly ok to me

Comment: We need to know what the issue is, are you getting a compiler error? Or is it not working when it is running fine?

Comment: To obtain an answer, explain the result you expect and the result you actually get.

Comment: there is no error.i m getting a failing grade for this part

Answer (score 1):

You probably start with `head == NULL`. Try checking for null-pointers:

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::insertAtHead(T item)
{
   ListItem<T> *node=new ListItem<T>(item);
   ListItem<T> *temp;

   temp=head;
   head=node;
   head->next=temp;
   if (temp)
       temp->prev=head;
}
```